# Kiama: dup illegal arguments exception

Tags: scala

I am getting `dup illegal arguments exception` in the following code.

```
package tests.kiama

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.kiama.rewriting.Rewriter._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class KiamaRewrite extends FunSuite {
    test("test1") {
        abstract class E
        case class B(l: E, r: E) extends E
        case class P() extends E
        case class Q() extends E
        case class PP() extends E
        case class QQ() extends E

        val t = B(P(), Q())
        val d = rule {
            case P() => PP()
            case Q() => QQ()
        }

        val s = bottomup(d)(t)
        println("done")
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: dup illegal arguments: public tests.kiama.KiamaRewrite$$anonfun$1$B$2(tests.kiama.KiamaRewrite$$anonfun$1,tests.kiama.KiamaRewrite$$anonfun$1$E$1,tests.kiama.KiamaRewrite$$anonfun$1$E$1) (PP(),QQ()), expects 3
```

I am using the kiama library. http://code.google.com/p/kiama/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kiama `dup` method is responsible for creating new instances of the same type as existing instances. `dup` uses reflection to find the constructor and is complaining that the constructor arguments do not match the arguments given. In your test it is trying to make a `B` node with two children, but the `B` constructor has three arguments because `B` is an inner class of `KiamaRewrite`.

Move the `B` etc class declarations out of `KiamaRewrite` and the test passes.

Comment: Does that also apply inner classes of traits?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Eventually you will need to mix the trait into a class and then inner classes of the trait will have an outer reference to the class instance.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way around that problem? Or where can I look more details up, to get a better understanding of that matter?

Comment: In normal Scala code it's not an issue because a use of (say) B above is always in the context of the KiamaRewrite class so the outer instance of KiamaRewrite to use for the B instance is clear. The Scala compiler takes care of that for you. The problem for Kiama is that we are rewriting generically, so all we have is the B node. The current version of Kiama is not clever enough to know what to do with the outer param for the constructor (and it's not clear that there is a general solution for a generic rewrite since you don't know what things are being rewritten into.

Comment: The workaround is to not use nested classes. If you want to hide those classes, you can put them in a object (module) and import them from there into the place where you do the rewrites.